# How to track which protein ID is linked to which gene ID with rentrez

Tags: r, bioconductor, ncbi, rentrez

I have a bunch of protein IDs and I want to fetch the corresponding coding sequences (CDSs) without loosing the protein ID. I have managed to download the corresponding CDSs, but unfortunately, CDSs IDs are very different from protein IDs in NCBI.

I have the following R code:

```
library(rentrez)
Prot_ids <- c("XP_012370245.1","XP_004866438.1","XP_013359583.1")
links <- entrez_link(dbfrom="protein", db="nuccore", id=Prot_ids, by_id = TRUE)
```

And then, I used this command to "match" protein IDs with CDS IDs:

```
lapply(links, function(x) x$links$protein_nuccore_mrna)

[[1]]
[1] "820968283"

[[2]]
[1] "861491027"

[[3]]
[1] "918634580"
```

However, as you can see the argument 'by_id=TRUE' just make a list of three elink objects but now I have lost the protein IDs.

I would want something like:

> Protein ID XP_012370245.1 XP_004866438.1 XP_013359583.1
>
> CDS ID XM_004866381.2 XM_012514791.1 XM_013504129.1

Any suggestion is very welcome, thanks!!

Comment: please make a reproducible example. E.g. where does `links2` come from?

Comment: Your can always do `names(links) <- Prot_ids` if the length and order is maintained.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, is just `links`, it should be `lapply(links, function(x) x$links$protein_nuccore_mrna)`. I will fix it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(rentrez)
Prot_ids <- c("XP_012370245.1","XP_004866438.1","XP_013359583.1")
links <- entrez_link(dbfrom="protein", db="nuccore", id=Prot_ids, by_id = TRUE)
linkids <- sapply(links, function(x) x$links$protein_nuccore_mrna)
##Get the summary for the gi record
linkNuc <- entrez_summary(id = linkids, db = "nuccore")

df <- data.frame(ProtIDs = Prot_ids[rep(sapply(links, function(x) length(x$links$protein_nuccore_mrna)))], 
                 linkids, 
                 NucID=sapply(strsplit(sapply(linkNuc, "[[", "extra"), split = "\\|"), "[", 4))

#                 ProtIDs   linkids          NucID
#820968283 XP_012370245.1 820968283 XM_012514791.1
#861491027 XP_012370245.1 861491027 XM_004866381.2
#918634580 XP_012370245.1 918634580 XM_013504129.1
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for, thank you very much!